# Send UITableViewCell across View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to select a UITableViewCell from my table view in one view controller and pass the data of the cell into another view controller.

Code:

```
-(void)pushView
{
myView.mainCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath     indexPathWithIndex:currentCell]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myView animated:YES];
}
```

`myView` is the view I want to push from my first view. 
`mainCell` is a UITableViewCell property of `myView`. I want it be exactly what the selected cell is.
`currentCell` is just an integer that returns the row number of the cell selected.

How can I pass one cell across view controllers?

Comment: Your cell should not contain any data to pass across. All the data should be held within the UITableViewController. This then just populates the Cell which just displays it. To pass the data elsewhere you just take that data from the UITableViewController and pass it across. Whether it is an NSArray, NSString, NSDictionary or a custom class.

Comment: So if I want the same cell to be seen in my other view controller I need to recreate it using the same information as the original cell? There isn't a way to just pass the whole cell?

Comment: @user2480176 It'll be much more complicated than passing the data you used to create the cell, then recreate it after: in the next VC, you'll have to use UITableView's protocols to populate your tableview, which will either way require the original data.

Comment: No, that would be very messy. The workflow should be such: your data model provides data to the first table. Maybe the model resides in the first view controller, maybe it's another object. When the user picks a cell from the table, your data model should forward the *data that populates your cell* to the next view controller, which would incorporate that data into its table there. Passing cell objects around will get messy with regards to memory management, and it's just all around hacky.

Comment: OK, I see what you want. Just writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need to pass the cells as it will mess up the references as commented by many people. Take a look at [this](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/passing-data-between-view-controllers/). Its discussing the same problem u r facing.

```
- (IBAction)nextScreenButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
DestinationViewController *destController = [[DestinationViewController alloc] init];
//pass the data here
destController.data = [SourceControllerDataSource ObjectAtIndex:currentCell];    

[self.navigationController pushViewController:destController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see what you want now.

What you want is to have some data displayed in a table view cell. Then to move somewhere else in the app and display the same data in a different table view but laid out in exactly the same way.

What you do then is this...

First create a new class which is a subclass of `UITableViewCell` call it something like `MyTableViewCell`.

The next part depends on whether you are using Interface Builder but I'll do everything in code for now.

In the new class create your interface properties in the .h file.

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *someImageView;
etc...

@end
```

Now in the .m file you can set it up like so...

@implementation MyTableViewCell

```
- (void)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        //set up your labels and add to the contentView.
        self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
        [self.contentView addSubView:self.nameLabel];

        self.someImageView = ...
        [self.contentView addSubView:self.someImageView];

        // and so on for all your interface stuff.
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Now in the `UITableViewController` that you want to use this cell you can do...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // other stuff

    [self.tableView registerClass:[MyTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomCellReuseIdentifier"];

    // other stuff
}
```

Then in cell for row...

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomCellReuseIdentifier"];

    customCell.nameLabel.text = //some string that you got from the data
    customCell.someImageView.image = //some image that you got from the data

    return customCell;
}
```

Doing this you can use the same cell layout in multiple places and all you have to do is populate the data.

When you pass the data to a new table view you can use the same cell class to re-populate it with the data that was passed around.

Never pass around a UIView or UIView subclass. They should not contain data that way. The are only used to display it.